# Calculating a certain pushforward of a vector field

Tags: differential-geometry, vector-fields, pushforward

So I'm new to differential geometry and this problem is giving me trouble, and more generally I'd just like to understand pushforwards of vector fields better. Let $\phi: \mathbb{S}^2\rightarrow\mathbb{R^2}$, $\phi(x,y,z) = (\frac{x}{1-z}, \frac{y}{1-z})$ and $\phi: \mathbb{S}^2\rightarrow\mathbb{R^2}$, $\psi(x,y,z) = (\frac{x}{1+z}, \frac{y}{1+z})$, and let $X$ be a vector field on $\mathbb{S^2}$ satisfying $\phi_*(X)(u,v) = (1,0)$ for all $(u,v) \in \mathbb{R}^2$. We want to find
$\psi_*(X)(u,v)$.

I really don't know how to start here. I understand the definition of the pushforward of a vector field, but it just seems so abstract and hard to do actual calculations with. Can anyone offer some insight?

Comment: It seems to me you should start by calculating the derivatives of $\phi$ and $\psi$. Have you done that? Note they are not (quite) defined on all of $\mathbb{S}^2$.

Comment: Right, I should have specified that the domains of $\phi$ and $\psi$ should really have (0,0,1) and (0,0,-1) removed, respectively. Getting their derivative matrices is easy enough, but from there I run into trouble trying to apply the definition of the pushforward-- (I think) I'd need to figure out an expression for $X$ somehow based on the condition for $\phi,$ and that's where I get stuck.

Comment: Have you computed the inverse mappings? Also do you know how pushforward interacts with composition and taking inverses?

Comment: Ah, I think you've poked me in the right direction-- since the $\phi$ and $\psi$ are invertible when restricted to $\mathbb{S^2}$ I can invert the derivative matrix of their composition with a chart on  $\mathbb{S^2}$ to remove the need of finding $X$ explicitly. I think I can take it from here; thanks for the tips!

Comment: No problem. If you're feeling energetic, answering your own questions is normal on this network and even encouraged, I think.

Comment: Here's another angle to try: Use a more concrete definition of the pushforward. Given a vector field $X$ on $S^2$ and a point $u \in S^2$ the pushforward of $X$ can be calculated as follows: Find a curve $c$ such that $c(0) - u$ and $c'(0) = X(u)$. Find the formula of $\phi\circ c(t)$. Then $(\phi\circ c)'(0)$ is the pushforward of $X(u)$.